# How does Compression work?

Tags: teradata

How does compression helps in saving table space? I tried to find the difference before and after compression on some columns,but i didn't find any difference.The columns i am compressing are varchar columns.Using the below queries. Please help.

```
ALTER TABLE GEEDW_D_PLP_BULK_T.CDR_PLP_FMEA_DEFECTS_BKP
 ADD CREATED_BY COMPRESS('TBPLP'),
 ADD LAST_UPDATED_BY COMPRESS('TBPLP'),
 ADD DW_UPDATED_BY COMPRESS('CDR');

SELECT SUM(CurrentPerm) FROM DBC.ALLSPACE WHERE
DatabaseName='GEEDW_D_PLP_BULK_T' AND  TableName='CDR_PLP_FMEA_DEFECTS_BKP'
```

Regards,

Comment: If the values in the COMPRESS exist in at least a few percent of the rows, you should see a difference. Can you show the actual sizes before/after?

Comment: Hi Dieter, 
SELECT SUM(CurrentPerm) FROM DBC.ALLSPACE WHERE
DatabaseName='GEEDW_D_PLP_BULK_T' AND     TableName='CDR_PLP_FMEA_DEFECTS_BKP'
--97,280.00

SELECT SUM(CurrentPerm) FROM DBC.ALLSPACE WHERE
DatabaseName='GEEDW_D_PLP_BULK_T' AND     TableName='CDR_PLP_FMEA_DEFECTS' 
--97,280.00

Comment: I am getting the exact no of bytes for both the table. _BKP is the one where i have applied compression.
ALTER TABLE GEEDW_D_PLP_BULK_T.CDR_PLP_FMEA_DEFECTS_BKP
 ADD CREATED_BY COMPRESS('TBPLP'),
 ADD LAST_UPDATED_BY COMPRESS('TBPLP'),
 ADD DW_UPDATED_BY COMPRESS('CDR');

These values are hardcoded for those columns.

Comment: There is 72 record in both the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Compress is only done (and useful) on large tables, but a table with 72 rows is definitely a very small one.

The compress values are added to the table header, which is stored on each AMP, increasing it's size. In your case you might have saved some perm space in the data blocks, but the table header increase compensated that.

So simply insert much more rows and you will see a difference.

Comment: Ok, Thanks a  lot Dieter. Let me check on a Bigger table. Will update you.